# Disputed "Not An Answer" Flag

Tags: discussion, flags, disputed-flags

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24427746/639233) some time ago, but only just realized the flag was disputed.

The answer makes a valid comment about xagyg's answer to the question, but is not an answer in its own right.

**Have I missed something? / Is there another reason for the flag to be disputed?**

Should I have edited xagyg's answer first?

Comment: That's definitely an attempt to answer the question. NAA is reserved for a different category. If you see technical problems, or the answer is incorrect, downvote it.

Comment: My impression was that the answer doesn't refer to the question, it's referring to one of the other answers.
If (for whatever reason) the other answer to this question was deleted; this answer wouldn't mean anything at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It was [disputed in review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5155614). It's not immediately obvious that this answer is a follow-on to the one by xagyg, and appears at first glance to be an answer on its own.

"not an answer" flags carry no context, so you can't assume that reviewers or moderators will see what you did. If it's not immediately obvious that something is a non-answer, I'd recommend using a custom flag stating

> This is a comment on xagyg's answer, describing a possible improvement to part of the code they present.

This makes it clear where we should look to decide if an answer should be removed or converted to a comment. Reviewers don't see other answers, and wouldn't have that context.